# Parse push notification with ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, parse.js

I am trying to set up a push notification with parse to handle received notifications.

I used [phonegap-parse-plugin](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin) plugin and was able to set it up correctly.

My problem with it is that I cannot handle the received notifications. I would like to redirect a user to a the page for the notification based on the notification json params.

So, I decided to switch to [parse-push-plugin](https://github.com/manishiitg/parse-push-plugin), but my problem with it is that I cannot even get it to show the alert registered box; it cannot even find the ParsePushPlugin method.

I followed the tutorial which is simple enough and added this to my app.js file

```
ParsePushPlugin.register(
    { appId:"xxx", clientKey:"xxx", eventKey:"myEventKey" }, //will trigger receivePN[pnObj.myEventKey]
    function() {
        alert('successfully registered device!');
    },
    function(e) {
        alert('error registering device: ' + e);
});

ParsePushPlugin.on('receivePN', function(pn){
    alert('yo i got this push notification:' + JSON.stringify(pn));
});
```

The alert success just failed to show so I guess it is not working or I am not doing the right thing.

Comment: Can now work. i had to load the parse js library.

Comment: It's a school-boy-error but we've all been there, I'm glad to hear you managed to figure it out!

Comment: What is eventkey in the parameters?

Comment: @raju just incase you have a custom event key.

Comment: Might want to post this as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).  It is easy to implement and use.

Config :

```
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "Your-sender-ID",
            "forceShow": true, // To show notifications on screen as well
            "iconColor": "#403782",
            "badge": "true",
            "clearBadge": "true" // To clear app badge
        },
        "ios": {
            "alert": "true",
            "badge": "true",
            "clearBadge": "true",
            "sound": "true",
            "forceShow": "true"
        },
        "windows": {}
    });
```

Device Registration :

```
    push.on('registration', function(data) {
            localStorage.setItem('pushToken', data.registrationId); // Save registration ID
    });
```

Handle Notifications

```
    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // Handle all requests here
        if (data.additionalData.$state == "mystate") {
            $state.go('app.conversations');
        }
    })
```