# Hide push notifications on Ionic app when app is running

Tags: ionic-framework, parse-platform, push-notification, ionic3

I am sending push notification from Parse server to an Ionic app, the app is using ParsePushPlugin:https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin

Following the instructions, I manage to receive push notifications correctly.

But even when my app is running in foreground, the plugin is still showing the notification on top of my app, which is extremely confusing.

I tried to listen to the event where push notification is received when app is running. But the notification is still showing:

```
ParsePushPlugin.on('receivePN', function(pn:any){
  console.log('yo i got this push notification:' + JSON.stringify(pn));
}, function(error:any){
  console.error( error);
});
```

How can I hide the notification when app is already running in foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in OPTIONS of push plugin, `forceShow` will hide notification on app foreground :

```
{
        "android": {
            "senderID": "XXXXXXXXXX",
            "forceShow": "false",
            "badge": "true"
            },
        "ios": {
            "alert": "true",
            "badge": "true",
            "sound": "true",
            "forceShow": "false"
        },
        "windows": {}
    }
```

[For more info you can click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771478/parse-push-notification-with-ionic/44432579#44432579)

Comment: Ah thanks. I am not using that plugin. But I will give that plugin a try...

Comment: Use this one Much easier : Let me know if any problems :) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771478/parse-push-notification-with-ionic/44432579#44432579

Comment: Does it matter if I am using parse to send the push notification and the plugin does not seem to be designed for parse?

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck at another strange problem while trying to use the plugin, can you help me take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156690/ionic-app-fails-to-launch-after-adding-phonegap-plugin-push-plugin

Answer (score 0):

At the end I realise the only way I can stop the notification is to modify ParsePushPlugin.m

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"User info %@", notification.request.content.userInfo);

    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [self jsCallback:notification.request.content.userInfo withAction:(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) ? @"RECEIVE" : @"OPEN"];

    //added this line to hide the notification
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);

    //commented out this line to hide the notification
    //completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}
```